# TYPO3: Automatically allow all the CE of an extension to be edited by a BE user group?

Tags: php, permissions, typo3, backend

For the members of my BE user group `Redakteur` to be able to edit the custom content elements (CE) of my extension, I have to go to edit the group in the BE: `Access Lists > Tables (modify)` and select all the tables of the extension, and then `Access Lists > Explicitly allow/deny field values` and select all the CEs of the extension.

Is there a way to automatically make all the CEs of my extension to be editable by the `Redakteur` group?

I've found that adding:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['explicitADmode'] = 'explicitDeny';
```

To the extension's `ext_localconf.php` makes all the CEs allowed (not their tables to be modified, though). The problem is that it allows all other elements from other extensions too, which might be a security concern, or wouldn't it?

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to make all content elements of your extension automatically available for all editors or editors of a specific user group.

I would **not** recommend to switch `[BE][explicitADmode]` to `explicitAllow` because that means that every time you install a new extension with content elements you need to adjust the editor rights.

What might be a solution (untested): You can use `explicitDeny` in combination with Page TSConfig and conditions to limit content elements for **all other user groups** but your group `Redakteur`.

So this might look like this:

```
[like(","~backend.user.userGroupList~",", "*,1,*")]
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType {
  removeItems = header, text, textpic, image, gridelements_pi1, myothercontentelement
}
[END]
```

But this would still mean that you need to adjust the above mentioned list of removed items each time you add a new extension.

Some links for your further research:

- [Page TSConfig Reference for TCEFORM](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html)
- [Reference for TypoScript and TSConfig Conditions](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Conditions.html) (TYPO3 9.5 and newer)
- [Reference for backend.user.userGroupList](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#backend-user-usergrouplist)